# toFade animation doing instantly, lenght property not working

Tags: xamarin.forms

I want to fadeIn and fadeOut my frame when Tapped. When I tap, it instantly fadeout and fadein although I set 3000 milliseconds.

I already tried Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread but not working too.

my xaml.cs:

```
private async void SelectedFrame_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        //Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread( async() => { await questionFrame.FadeTo(0, 3000, Easing.SinInOut); });
        await questionFrame.FadeTo(0, 3000, Easing.SinInOut); 
    }
```

xaml:

```
 <Frame x:Name="questionFrame"
                       HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                       HasShadow="False"
                       VerticalOptions="Start"
                       BackgroundColor="WhiteSmoke"
                       CornerRadius="10">
                    <StackLayout Margin="20">
                        <Label Text="{Binding CurrentQuestionText}" FontSize="Micro"/>
                        <Label HeightRequest="10"/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding CurrentQuestion.Quest}"
                               FontSize="Subtitle"/>
                        <Label HeightRequest="20"/>
                        <Frame CornerRadius="10" Padding="10"
                               BorderColor="GhostWhite"
                               BackgroundColor="White">
                            <Label Text="{Binding CurrentQuestion.AnswerA}"
                               FontSize="Small">
                                <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                                    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding GoToNextQuestionCommand}" Tapped="SelectedFrame_Tapped"/>
                                </Label.GestureRecognizers>
                            </Label>
                        </Frame>
                    </StackLayout>
                </Frame>
```

Comment: It actually works as expected. It "seems" instantly because the background colors of both the frame and its container is similar. Try to set background color for the parent of frame like BackgroundColor="Red" and observe it again.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why but when I build my code in Xamarin.Forms 3.4 the animation works how ever when I update to Xamarin.Forms 4.2 it does not.

It was bugged, It fixed with Xamarin.Forms 4.3
https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/7291